# Не отображаеться картинка в боксах flex. Нижние боксы налазят на верхние. Путь к картинке указан верно

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, flexbox

```
 .moduls-box {
  margin: 87px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around; 
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.heder-01 {
  background-image: url("../layers/jpg/block_1.jpg");
  border-color: transparent;
  background-position: left center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto;
}

.heder-02 {
  background-image: url(../layers/jpg/block_2.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.heder-03 {
  background-image: url(../layers/jpg/block_3.jpg);
  border-color: transparent;
}

.heder-04 {
  background-image: url(../layers/jpg/block_4.jpg);
  border-color: transparent;
  }

.box {
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  border: none solid gray;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px gray;
}

.footer-tile {
  text-align: right;
  opacity: 0.15;
  font-size: 48px;
  display: block;
  margin: 25px;
}



<div class="moduls-box">
        
        <div class="box">            
          <div class="heder-01"></div>
            <div class="body-box">
             <h3>Введение</h3>
              <ul>
               <li>Как работают сайты. Верстка</li>
               <li>Возможности HTML, CSS, JS</li>
               <li>Редактор кода. Coderen</li>
               <li>Работа с DevTools</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          <span class="footer-tile">01</span>
      </div>
            <div class="box">
        <div class="heder-02"></div>
        <div class="body-box">
          <h3>Базовый HTML</h3>
            <ul>
              <li>Базовые теги</li>
              <li>Теги картинок и ссылок</li>
              <li>Теги таблиц</li>
              <li>Кодстайл HTML</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <span class="footer-tile">02</span>
      </div>


      <div class="box">
        <div class="heder-03"></div>
        <div class="body-box">
          <h3>Базовый CSS</h3>
            <ul>
              <li>Подключение CSS</li>
              <li>Вес селектора</li>
              <li>Свойства display</li>
              <li>Блочная модель и позиционирование</li>
              <li>Кодстайл CSS</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <span class="footer-tile">03</span>
      </div>


      <div class="box">
        <div class="heder-04"></div>
          <div class="body-box">
            <h3>Работа с макетом</h3>
              <ul>
                <li>Про формы изоброжений</li>
                <li>Работа с макетом в Photoshop</li>
                <li>Работа с макетом в Figma </li>                  
              </ul>
          </div>
          <span class="footer-tile">04</span>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<div>` с картинкой должен иметь высоту и ширину, которую вы забыли прописать в css.

```css
.moduls-box {
  margin: 87px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 25px; /*---*/
}

.heder-01 {
  /*background: url("../layers/jpg/block_1.jpg") #eee;*/
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1642425149556-b6f90e946859') #eee 0 0 /cover;
  border-color: transparent;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.heder-02 {
  background-image: url(../layers/jpg/block_2.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.heder-03 {
  background-image: url(../layers/jpg/block_3.jpg);
  border-color: transparent;
}

.heder-04 {
  background-image: url(../layers/jpg/block_4.jpg);
  border-color: transparent;
}

.box {
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  border: none solid gray;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px gray;
  min-width: 300px; /*---*/
}

.footer-tile {
  text-align: right;
  opacity: 0.15;
  font-size: 48px;
  display: block;
  margin: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="moduls-box">

  <div class="box">
    <div class="heder-01"></div>
    <div class="body-box">
      <h3>Введение</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Как работают сайты. Верстка</li>
        <li>Возможности HTML, CSS, JS</li>
        <li>Редактор кода. Coderen</li>
        <li>Работа с DevTools</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <span class="footer-tile">01</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="heder-02"></div>
    <div class="body-box">
      <h3>Базовый HTML</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Базовые теги</li>
        <li>Теги картинок и ссылок</li>
        <li>Теги таблиц</li>
        <li>Кодстайл HTML</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <span class="footer-tile">02</span>
  </div>


  <div class="box">
    <div class="heder-03"></div>
    <div class="body-box">
      <h3>Базовый CSS</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Подключение CSS</li>
        <li>Вес селектора</li>
        <li>Свойства display</li>
        <li>Блочная модель и позиционирование</li>
        <li>Кодстайл CSS</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <span class="footer-tile">03</span>
  </div>


  <div class="box">
    <div class="heder-04"></div>
    <div class="body-box">
      <h3>Работа с макетом</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Про формы изоброжений</li>
        <li>Работа с макетом в Photoshop</li>
        <li>Работа с макетом в Figma </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <span class="footer-tile">04</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю! Тем не менее heder-04 налез на верхние блоки и при одинаковой высоты и ширины во всех блоках (height: 180px;
  width: 100%;) они выглядят координально разных размеров. Подскажите?

Comment: @AndreySuhodolskiy Дополнил свой код. Стили которые я дописал, справа имеют комментарий `/*---*/`. Стиль `gap: ..` отвечает за отступы между `flex` блоками.

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, почему картинка не отображается: `.heder-*` - пустые блоки => их высота = 0, поэтому картинки не видно. Добавьте класс `heder-*` непосредственно к самому блоку `.box`.

Answer (score 0):

> Нижние боксы налазят на верхние

Есть идея для костыльного решения: создать @media запрос в файле css, в котором следует указать max-width, при котором у элементов heder-1 и heder-2 сработает margin-bottom.

То есть

```
@media (max-width: 1168px) {
 .heder-1 {
   margin-bottom: 10px
  }
}
```

Аналогичное действие для .heder-2